# Angular.JS Sub-Array access [& parsing a key]

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

It's my first time trying to build something with angular , and i find myself not able to retrieve some JSON data.

The data is retrieve from a SQL database in JSON form then passed to a template thanks to  angular route :

```
.when('/tasks/:TaskID',{
    templateUrl: 'template/task_data_template.html',
    controller:"showTaskData",
    controllerAs: 'STD'
})
```

The showTaskData is defined as follow :

```
angular.module('moonDive').controller('showTaskData',function($http,$routeParams){

var store = this; 

store.tasks= [];

json_Url = 'api/tasks_data.php?TaskID=' + $routeParams.TaskID;


$http.get(json_Url).success(function(data){
    store.tasks = data; 
})});
```

My Data have this structure : 
[image: Data Structure]

This is accessible from the template html by :

```
{{STD.tasks[1]}}
```

Which return the data in that "JSON" way :

```
{
    "ActionID": "1",
    "Taskref": "1",
    "Ast1_1": "",
    "Ast2_1": "Start EVA watch\nopen           hatch\nAssist CDR",
    "Ast3_1": "",
    "Ast1_2": "Egress cabin to LM porch\nReceive &      jetttison bag\nReceive ETB/LEC",
    "Ast2_2": "Deploy CDR PLSS antenna\nHand jettison      bag to CDR\nHand ETB/LEC to CDR",
    "Ast3_2": "",
    "Ast1_3": "Descend lander to top rung\nUnlock and deploy MESA\nLower ETB on LEC",
    "Ast2_3": "Tape recorder -off\nVerify voice signals level and uitlity floo [......]"
}
```

So far so good, so my final purpose is to have a table with two column (ast1 , ast2) and X row for X task. I'm not really sure how to begin , but i've tried something like that :

```
<table class="bordered hoverable responsive-table">
<tbody>

<tr ng-repeat="boo in STD.tasks[1]">
<td style=" color: blue;" ng-if="$odd"> {{boo}}</td>
<td style="color:red" ng-if="$even"> {{boo}}</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Well no luck it doesn't work at all, but one weird thing that prevent me to understand what's going on is that it displays all the information but in what seems to be a random order.

[image]

I'd like to delete rows with "1" ; usually i would do a ng-if="boo.NameOfTheRow" ;  but here i don't really have access to this name do I ?

So my question is : How to delete the unnecessary data?  And how can I  arrange my data by Astr1 and 2 (for the columns) and task 1 to X (for the rows)

Thanks a lot !

PS : 
The generated code should look like that :

```
<table>

<thead>
    <td> task </td>
    <td> Astr 1 </td>
    <td> Astr 2 </td>
    <td> Astr 3 </td>
</thead>

<tbody> 
<tr>
    <td> 1</td>
    <td> {{STD.tasks[1].Ast1_1}} </td>
    <td> {{STD.tasks[1].Ast2_1}}</td>
    <td>{{STD.tasks[1].Ast3_1}}   </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td> 2</td>
    <td> {{STD.tasks[1].Ast1_2}} </td>
    <td> {{STD.tasks[1].Ast2_2}}</td>
    <td>{{STD.tasks[1].Ast3_2}}   </td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td> 3</td>
    <td> {{STD.tasks[1].Ast1_3}} </td>
    <td> {{STD.tasks[1].Ast2_3}}</td>
    <td>{{STD.tasks[1].Ast3_3}}   </td>
</tr>

....
<tr>
    <td> 7</td>
    <td> {{STD.tasks[1].Ast1_7}} </td>
    <td> {{STD.tasks[1].Ast2_7}}</td>
    <td>{{STD.tasks[1].Ast3_7}}   </td>
</tr>


    </tbody></table>
```

Thus the data should be displayed as : 
[image]

Comment: I've thought about using [ | orderBy :'...' ] but again the task is included in the name of each column, can't figure out how to access to this.

ps : if it isn't clear enough : astr1_2   (The [1] correspond to Astr and the [2] correspond to task . )

Answer (score 0):

If your `STD.tasks` is an array of entries, then you need to simply change your ng-repeat to `ng-repeat="boo in STD.tasks"`.

You should be getting back JSON data in array form:

```
[
  {"field":"value", "field2": "value"},
  {"field":"value", "field2": "value"},
  {"field":"value", "field2": "value"},
  ...
]
```

ng-repeat will want to iterate over each of those values in the array. Right now, you've pointed it to the very first item in the array, so it's repeating over each property in the object.

Comment: I had tried that , but it is exactly the problem , I have two object in my JSON dataset : the first one has an all other sort of information ; the second one has all the task/astr information 
Thanks !

if i do what you told me  it returns a table with two rows :https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/Cx29dTJPg7wVMhqPQ95W_X_sDbr1uQ5PTeIZRVHTkqk=w1919-h171-no

Comment: Oh, you're getting a single task? In that case, you don't need to ng-repeat. There is just one, so just write in the individual fields you want to display.

Comment: :) the problem is there can be up to ast3_10  : so it's kinda a hassle to write this by hand (and not very clean :) )

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear about the structure , i've made a table that ressemble the look of what I want. 

But the problem is maybe that STD.tasks[1] is read as a STRING and not a angular object ? 

meaning that STD.task is successfuly transformed from JSON to Angular object , but STD.Task[0] and [1] stayed as a JSON string ?